# Are ore and gem locations randomized?

Tags: steamworld-dig

When starting a new game of Steamworld Dig, are the ore and gem locations randomized?

For example: let’s say I find a rare diamond underground. Will that diamond be in the same place if I start a second playthrough?

Answer (score 1):

I think so, when I compared my playthrough with others from random youtubes videos I could find, it certainly feel randomly generated